# Why/How is my code causing a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, setinterval, spotfire

I have written the following JavaScipt code within a Spotfire TextArea.  I include the application and tag for completeness, but I don't believe my issue is Spotfire-specific.  Essentially, I have a timer which runs every 5 minutes, and clicks on a link (`clickLink('Foo');`) to trigger execution of some Python code elsewhere in the application.  If the application also contains a timestamp of the last full update, which occurs every 30 minutes in the same manner (`clickLink('Foo');`):

```
function reportTimestamp() {
  var timeNow = new Date();
  var hoursNow = timeNow.getHours();
  var minutesNow = timeNow.getMinutes();
  var secondsNow = timeNow.getSeconds();
  return hoursNow + ":" + minutesNow + ":" + secondsNow;
};

function timeBasedReaction(timestampAge){
  if (timestampAge >= 1800) {
    clickLink('Foo');
    clickLink('Bar');
  } else if (timestampAge >= 300) {
    clickLink('Foo');
  };
};
/*
function timeBasedReaction_B(timestampAge){
  if (timestampAge >= 300) {
    clickLink('Foo');
    if (timestampAge >= 1800) {
      clickLink('Bar');
    };
  };
};
*/
function clickLink(linkName) {
  var clickTarget = document.getElementById(linkName).children[0];
  clickTarget.click();
};

function checkTimestampAge() {
  console.log(reportTimestamp());
  var myTimeStamp = document.getElementById('Timestamp').children[0]
  var timeStampMS = new Date(myTimeStamp.textContent).getTime();
  var currentDateMS = new Date().getTime();
  var timestampAgeSeconds = (currentDateMS - timeStampMS)/1000;
  timeBasedReaction(timestampAgeSeconds);
};

function pageInitialization() {
  checkTimestampAge();
  var myTimer = null;
  var timerInterval = 300000;
  myTimer = setInterval(function(){checkTimestampAge()},timerInterval);
}

pageInitialization();
```

For reasons unclear to me, running this code in the application or in a web browser starts off fine, but eventually leads to very large memory allocation.
I've tried to read
[4 Types of Memory Leaks in JavaScript and How to Get Rid Of Them](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/), 
[JS setInterval/setTimeout Tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks#setinterval-settimeout), and 
[An interesting kind of JavaScript memory leak](https://blog.meteor.com/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak-8b47d2e7f156#.5s119jqo2), and it's a start, but I don't know enough to really understand what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it.

Thanks, and sorry for the huge block of text.

Comment: Is there any path that would lead to `pageInitialization` being called more than once, thus starting multiple intervals?

Comment: What do the event handlers for those clicked elements do?

Comment: @squint Good question!  In the application, the answer is actually "yes," because updating a Javascript file re-appends it to the document, but doesn't reload the page, resulting in multiple instances of the Javascript file itself running concurrently.

In the web browser, I believe the answer is "no."  The code is intended to run when the page loads, and it was my understanding that it would stop/be cleared if the page was re-loaded or someone navigated away from it.

Comment: @Pointy When the links are clicked they execute a Python script which reloads imported data tables.  In the case of `Foo` only one table is updated, while in the case of `Bar` several tables are updated and the HTML of a different portion of the page is updated.

Comment: Also, I included `timeBasedReaction()` and a commented-out `timeBasedReaction()_B` because I wanted to ask if either form was considered "more correct."  It's not really within the scope of the overall question, though; it was more "two birds with one stone."
Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: The logic in `_B` is equivalent and I wouldn't say one is "more correct" than the other. I'd prefer `_B` personally.

Comment: I do see that you're assigning the interval ID to `myTimer`, which is in the same scope, but then you're not using that variable. Do you have another `myTimer` variable in the enclosing scope that you were trying to use with `clearInterval`?

Comment: @squint In a previous version of the code, myTimer was declared globally and `clearInterval(myTimer);` was part of `checkTimestampAge()`.  I suspected that running the python scripts and re-generating the page HTML would cause additional instances of the Javascript code to be appended and additional `myTimer`s to be active.

`if (timestampAgeSeconds >= 1800) {`

`while (myTimer != null) {`

`clearInterval(myTimer);`
`myTimer = null;`
`}`

`clickLink('Bar');`

`var myTimer = setInterval(function(){checkTimestampAge()},timerInterval);
    };`

Comment: When clearing the entire document, I don't know how different implementations will treat the JS. I would however try to clear the interval first just in case. If you had a global `myTimer` but then declared another one inside `checkTimestampAge()` and used that to first clear the interval, it would actually be using the *local* version, not the global because of how `var` declarations work in JS. Doesn't matter that it was declared later in the function. All `var` decls get processed first, so it's as though they appear at the top of the function. And the assignment wouldn't reach the global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This causes a memory leak because of how Spotfire handles Javascript which has been associated with/loaded into a TextArea.

Both in the desktop client, as well as in the Webplayer instance, when the page is loaded, all the portions of that page are loaded, include the TextArea and including the Javascript associated therein.  My previous understanding in the comments above:

`"the code is intended to run when the page loads, and it was my understanding that it would stop/be cleared if the page was re-loaded or someone navigated away from it"`

was incorrect.  One of the script's actions was to update/redraw the HTML location in the TextArea.  This, in turn, reloads the TextArea **but does not clear the existing Javascript code**.  However, it's not really accessible anymore, either, since `var myTimer = null` actually creates a new `myTimer` rather than nulling-out the existing one.  In this way, instances of `myTimer` increase geometrically as instances of `function timeBasedReaction` run and continually update the underlying TextArea and load in more of the same Javascript.

To anyone who ha a similar issue and come here, it's been over 3 months and I haven't figured out how to solve this once and for all.  If I do, I'll try to come back with another update.